# Powershell - Get Sequence Between Hyphenated Numbers and Copy Files

Tags: powershell

The user enters a hyphenated sequence, for instance 12-18. I need to copy a file from on directory to separate existing folders all named Folder12, Folder13, Folder14....Folder18. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is unclear as to your objective. Please clarify and also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. I honestly just didn't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to provide you with the whole script, but I will answer what I can see as the tricky bit to this problem: turning "12-18" into something Powershell can iterate over.

```
#User Input
$param = "12-18" 

#Split the string by "-", and assign to variables.
$start = $param.Split("-")[0]
$end = $param.Split("-")[1]

# using the ".." range operator you can now iterate through each number
$start..$end | foreach { 
    Write-host $_ 
    #Here is where you can put your file copy code.
}
```